# Json Array PHP Youtube Api v2 cannot receive string from $t

Tags: php, json, youtube

I get channel json information from the youtube api v2 with following code:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/lefloid?alt=json"),true);
```

And then try to get the author name

```
echo $json["entry"]["author"][0]["name"]["$t"];
```

But this code doesnt work so I try find the problem.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/lefloid?alt=json"),true)["entry"]["author"][0]["name"];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
echo "</pre>";
```

output:

```
Array([$t] => LeFloid)
```

but the echo after this code doesnt work

```
echo $json["$t"];
```

How can I get finally the author name?

Comment: The problem is that `"$t"` is treated as variable `$t`. You have to use single quotes instead of double: `echo $json['$t'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will produce the author's name.

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/lefloid?alt=json"),true);
    print_r($json['entry']['author'][0]['name']['$t']);
?>
```

When you tried

> echo $json["$t"];

it wouldn't work because you were tyring to access `$t` at the top level of the array when it needs to be preceded by `$json["entry"]['author'][0]['name']`